# Keep only first n characters in a string?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way in JavaScript to remove the end of a string?

I need to only keep the first 8 characters of a string and remove the rest.

Answer (score 781, accepted):

```js
const result = 'Hiya how are you'.substring(0,8);
console.log(result);
console.log(result.length);
```

You are looking for JavaScript's `String` method `substring`

e.g.

```
'Hiya how are you'.substring(0,8);
```

Which returns the string starting at the first character and finishing before the 9th character - i.e. 'Hiya how'.

[substring documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)

Comment: weird that there is no a `str.left(n);` function in javascript. Obviously it should return the `n` leftmost characters of the string. Like `str.slice(-n);` returns the `n` rightmost characters of the string ...

Comment: `String.prototype.substr()` is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr)

Answer (score 98):

You could use `String.slice`:

```
var str = '12345678value';
var strshortened = str.slice(0,8);
alert(strshortened); //=> '12345678'
```

Using this, a String extension could be:

```
String.prototype.truncate = String.prototype.truncate ||
  function (n){
    return this.slice(0,n);
  };
var str = '12345678value';
alert(str.truncate(8)); //=> '12345678'
```

[See also](https://github.com/KooiInc/PureHelpers#truncatestring)

Comment: +1 because str.slice() allows you to make the second argument negative to count from the back, unlike str.substring: `"abcdef".slice(0, -2) == "abcd"`.

Answer (score 25):

Use **substring** function
Check this out http://jsfiddle.net/kuc5as83/

```
var string = "1234567890"
var substr=string.substr(-8);
document.write(substr);

Output >> 34567890
```

`substr(-8)` will keep last 8 chars

```
var substr=string.substr(8);
document.write(substr);

Output >> 90
```

`substr(8)` will keep last 2 chars

```
var substr=string.substr(0, 8);
document.write(substr);

Output >> 12345678
```

`substr(0, 8)` will keep first 8 chars

Check this out
    [string.substr(start,length)](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp)

Comment: Will delete or keep last 8 chars?

Answer (score 8):

You could try:

```
myString.substring(0, 8);
```

Comment: (0,7) will give the first 7 characters

Comment: Yea you're right, the second index is a stop point and not included in the return value.  Fixed.

Answer (score 8):

```
var myString = "Hello, how are you?";
myString.slice(0,8);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `string.substring(from, to)` [API](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp). In your case, use `string.substring(0,8).`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring), which returns a potion of a string:

```
"abcdefghijklmnopq".substring(0, 8) === "abcdefgh"; // portion from index 0 to 8
```