# Javascript function in td element with passing parameter

Tags: javascript, php, html, web, parameter-passing

I have the following `<td>` element that displays data retrieved from the database to display the followers an artist has.

```
<td>
    <span id="followers">
        <? echo empty($artist['Artist']['followers']) ? 'N/A' : number_format($artist['Artist']['followers']);?>
    </span>
</td>
```

There are some values that are very large and go upto 6 digits. 
I want to write a Javascript function that will take the substring and only display first 3 digits.

How can I write a function and pass the parameter as the value of : `$artist['Artist']['followers']`

I can do this in PHP, but I need to do it in javascript.

Comment: I want to use substring method because in other elemnts I have large strings that I need to truncate using the same method

Comment: This may help,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7708819/keep-only-first-n-characters-in-a-string

Answer (score 0):

Shortening method (can pass extraction indexes as params):

```
/* USAGE:
str - string to truncate;
start - start index, character position in the string, from which the string should start. Deafault: 0;
end - end index, character position in the string, at which the string should end. Deafault: 3;
*/

function shorten(str, start, end){
    // use .trim() to remove whitespaces from the string
    return str.trim().substring((start !== undefined ? start : 0),(end !== undefined ? end : 3));
}
```

This way you can shorten the text inside `<span>` of each `<td>` element on the page using pure Javascript:

```
var td = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
// loop through the <td> elements:
for(var i=0; i<td.length; i++){
    // find <span> element inside <td>:
    var el = td[i].querySelector('span');
    // extract <span> text and truncate. Using default start and end indexes in the function:
    el.innerText = shorten(el.innerText);
    // Using custom start and end indexes (5 characters. Start at 0, end at 5'th character):
    //el.innerText = shorten(el.innerText, 0, 5);
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/a0jwzmxs/)

or using jQuery:

```
$('td span').each(function(){
    $(this).text(shorten($(this).text()));
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jbazq6pk/)

**NOTE**:
Make sure that each `<span>` element has **unique** `id`