# Truncate a copied web text

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code does exactly what I want: add copyright information to the bottom of the copied web text. However, it copies the entire article. I would like to restrict it to say 50 words or 200 characters. How should I proceed?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    document.body.oncopy = function () {
        var body_element = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
        var selection;
        selection = window.getSelection();
        var pagelink = "<br />Read more at: <a href='" + document.location.href + "'>" + document.location.href + "</a><br />";
        var copytext = selection + pagelink;
        var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
        body_element.appendChild(newdiv);
        newdiv.innerHTML = copytext;
        selection.selectAllChildren(newdiv);
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            body_element.removeChild(newdiv);
        }, 0);
    };
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/xx51vm2L/)**

I don't know to use `substring` or the above code doesn't use `write` function.

Comment: 200 _characters_ should be easy: `.substring(0, 200)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keep only first n characters in a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7708819/keep-only-first-n-characters-in-a-string)

Comment: Where do I add this `substring`? I saw the example but it uses write function and there's no write function here. I'm not very good with JS.

Comment: This is a method of `string` (or `String`), so you would simply do `copytext.substring(0, 200)`. The linked duplicate has an explanation for this.

Comment: Bear in mind that substring will _return_ the new string, not modify the already existing one in place. I.e. you'd do: `copytext = copytext.substring(0, 200)`

Comment: Thank you. I added this line as suggested without removing anything in the current code and it worked; `copytext = copytext.substring(0, 200) + pagelink;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added some extra instructions into your code. Firstly, cut first 200 characters (if there's more than 200 characters) from copied text, secondly, if there is more than 50 words, cut first 50 words. Try to change the `wordsLimit` and `charactersLimit` variable's values to figure out the effect.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    document.body.oncopy = function () {
     var wordsLimit = 50;
        var charactersLimit = 200;
        var body_element = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
        var selection;
        selection = window.getSelection();
        var limitChar = selection.toString().slice(0,charactersLimit);
  var limitWord = limitChar;
        var iter = 0;
        var end = null;
        limitWord.replace(/\s/g,function(a,b){
          iter++;
          if(iter===wordsLimit) limitWord = limitWord.slice(0,b);
        });
      
        var pagelink = "<br />Read more at: <a href='" + document.location.href + "'>" + document.location.href + "</a><br />";
        var copytext = limitWord + pagelink;
        var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
        body_element.appendChild(newdiv);
        newdiv.innerHTML = copytext;
        selection.selectAllChildren(newdiv);
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            body_element.removeChild(newdiv);
        }, 0);
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam hendrerit orci vel urna tincidunt, id aliquet leo dapibus. Nunc sodales arcu auctor, aliquam augue ut, blandit lorem. Ut eleifend dui in interdum fringilla. Etiam eleifend, sem et varius ornare, massa tellus tincidunt metus, ac ultricies ex diam ac arcu. Pellentesque at scelerisque ex. Quisque lobortis lectus sit amet porttitor dapibus. Nunc eget sagittis enim. Aenean mollis rutrum ante. Etiam lacinia aliquam pellentesque. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam hendrerit orci vel urna tincidunt, id aliquet leo dapibus. Nunc sodales arcu auctor, aliquam augue ut, blandit lorem. Ut eleifend dui in interdum fringilla. Etiam eleifend, sem et varius ornare, massa tellus tincidunt metus, ac ultricies ex diam ac arcu. Pellentesque at scelerisque ex. Quisque lobortis lectus sit amet porttitor dapibus. Nunc eget sagittis enim. Aenean mollis rutrum ante. Etiam lacinia aliquam pellentesque. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam hendrerit orci vel urna tincidunt, id aliquet leo dapibus. Nunc sodales arcu auctor, aliquam augue ut, blandit lorem. Ut eleifend dui in interdum fringilla. Etiam eleifend, sem et varius ornare, massa tellus tincidunt metus, ac ultricies ex diam ac arcu. Pellentesque at scelerisque ex. Quisque lobortis lectus sit amet porttitor dapibus. Nunc eget sagittis enim. Aenean mollis rutrum ante. Etiam lacinia aliquam pellentesque. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam hendrerit orci vel urna tincidunt, id aliquet leo dapibus. Nunc sodales arcu auctor, aliquam augue ut, blandit lorem. Ut eleifend dui in interdum fringilla. Etiam eleifend, sem et varius ornare, massa tellus tincidunt metus, ac ultricies ex diam ac arcu. Pellentesque at scelerisque ex. Quisque lobortis lectus sit amet porttitor dapibus. Nunc eget sagittis enim. Aenean mollis rutrum ante. Etiam lacinia aliquam pellentesque. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</p>
<p>This is the last line</p>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. btw, how do I do if I have to truncate only words and not characters? How do I make character truncate optional when words truncate is in place?

Comment: remove `.slice(0,charactersLimit)` from `selection.toString().slice(0,charactersLimit);` so that it'll look like `var limitChar = selection.toString();`