# How to get the middle Characters in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, telerik

I just want to Get hello in Label1

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
     result = "helloworld"         
     document.getElementById('<%= Label1.ClientID %>').innerHTML = result;
</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keep only first n characters in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7708819/keep-only-first-n-characters-in-a-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried doing result.substring(0,5);

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
 result = "helloworld"         
 document.getElementById('<%= Label1.ClientID %>').innerHTML = result.substring(0,5);
</script>
```

Comment: no problem, please tick this answer as it has answered your question to let others know this will help

Answer (score 1):

With `result.slice(start, end)` you can cut the string.
For `"HelloWorld"` that would look like
`result.slice(0, 5)`.

If you want to cut until the  half of the string just do 
`result.slice(0, floor(result.length/2))`.

[Source: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_string.asp](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_string.asp)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about your label reference, but setting HTML with `document.getElementById("mylabel").innerHTML = result;` does the trick. Best try with a straight forward label like `("mylabel")` for testing.