# TS map list of string dates to list of string years

Tags: arrays, typescript, date

I have a list of dates in string format, like this:

```
0: "2020-07-10T00:00:00"
1: "1999-01-01T00:00:00"
2: "2020-06-16T00:00:00"
```

I need to map it in such a way, so I will have a list of year strings- like this:

```
0: "2020"
1: "1999"
2: "2020"
```

My way of thinking is trimming the start of the string, then appending it to the new list of years.

What is the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keep only first n characters in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7708819/keep-only-first-n-characters-in-a-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `map` to transform your given array. Each element needs to be split by `-` and then use `substr(0, 4)` to get the first 4 chars, which are the year.

```
const myArr = ["2020-07-10T00:00:00", "1999-01-01T00:00:00", "2020-06-16T00:00:00"];
const result = myArr.map(v => v.substr(0, 4));
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Date#getFullYear` method.

```js
["2020-07-10T00:00:00", "1999-01-01T00:00:00", "2020-06-16T00:00:00"]
  .map(date => new Date(date).getFullYear())
```