# Limiting characters in my description to 140 characters with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, api

I'm working on a project that requires a list of books to be printed onto the page using an api url.

Code works wonders, but I'm struggling to limit the characters to 140 for the description as requested.

```
function renderItemHtml(item) {
return `<div class="book"><img src="${item.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail}" class="thumbnails" 
alt="${item.singleTitle} by ${item.volumeInfo.authors[0]}" />
<div>
<h4>${item.volumeInfo.title}</h4>
<p><strong>${item.volumeInfo.authors}</strong></p>
<h8>${item.volumeInfo.description}</h8>        <-------- what i need to limit
</div>
<br>
<h8>Pages:  ${item.volumeInfo.pageCount}</h8>
</div>`
```

}

Comment: [String.prototype.substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keep only first n characters in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7708819/keep-only-first-n-characters-in-a-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do this:

```
<h8>${item.volumeInfo.description.slice(0,140)}</h8>
```