# Typescript (playwright) how to match partially from array values?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, playwright

I'm using playwright to test some table data, some of which includes a datetime.  This datetime includes a timestamp, which can change based on when the data has changed.  I don't care too much about the timestamp, just the day it was last modified.  I'm looking for a way in my expect().toHaveText(['string array here']) to ignore the timestamp.  See code example below:

This fails because I'm not expecting the time stamp.

```
const tableRowData = this.page.locator(`//table[@class="myTableClass"]//td`)  //['John', 'Smith', 'Ohio', 'Aug 22, 2023 09:44 AM EST']
await expect(tableRowData).toHaveText('John', 'Smith', 'Ohio', 'Aug 22, 2023');
```

Due to timing, or delays in updates in the database, I don't want to try and test the timestamp to the minute/second, the day is sufficient.  Is there a good way to do this in the toHaveText() expect method?  I'm pretty sure I can do something that looks at the nth td tag, using regular expressions to return a string without the timestamp, but I was hoping to keep the test looking cleaner but just using toHaveText() with a string array in it.

For example:

```
const tableRowData = this.page.locator(`//table[@class="myTableClass"]//td`).nth(3) //'Aug 22, 9:44 AM EST
const dataWithoutTimeStamp = getDateWithoutTimeStamp(tableRowData) // Regex in this method to return only 'Aug 22, 2023'
expect(dataWithoutTimeStamp).toHaveText('Aug 22, 2023');
```

My goal is to avoid having to check each td value individually, for example:

```
expect(firstTd).toHaveText('John');
expect(secondTd).toHaveText('Smith');
// ... 10 more td's
expect(dataWithoutTimeStamp).toHaveText('Aug 22, 2023');
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly is the error you are getting currently?

Comment: The error is received
- Expected - 1
+ Received + 
[
    "John",
    "Smith",
    "Ohio",
    - "Aug 22, 2023",
    + "Aug 22, 2023 09:44 AM EST"
]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keep only first n characters in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7708819/keep-only-first-n-characters-in-a-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In playwright how to match partially from array values?

Use [toContainText](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locatorassertions#locator-assertions-to-contain-text):

`toContainText` matches partial text in the array compared to `toHaveText` which expects full text to match in the array.

```
await expect(tableRowData).toContainText('John', 'Smith', 'Ohio', 'Aug 22, 2023');
```

If you pass an array as an expected value, for `toContainText` the expectations are:

- Locator resolves to a list of elements.
- Elements from a subset of
  this list contain text from the expected array, respectively.
- The matching subset of elements has the same order as the expected
  array.
- Each text value from the expected array is matched by some element
  from the list.

Comment: Thanks, this will work to get a substring, but I'm looking to find a way to do it in the toHaveText() method, where we pass it 'Aug 22, 2023'.  Maybe using this on the string array before expecting.  For example tableRowData[3] = tableRowData[3].slice(0, 12);  Then expect(tableRowData).toHaveText(['John', 'Smith', 'Ohio', 'Aug 22, 2023']);  I will give this a try

Comment: Yes!  Thank you, both your first answer (manipulating the array before expect) and using to ContainText instead of toHaveText worked.  Using toContainText accomplished the same thing, in a much cleaner way though.  Thanks for the quick answer!